# Angular JS and Flask RESTful API

Tags: python, angularjs, cors, flask-restful

I am currently developing a site which uses Angular JS for the front-end framework and Flask for the RESTful API. I am using vagrant to host the LAMP server where my app resides. The API was tested using curl, and it works exactly as I want it to.

I get the following error when I run the app:

```
`*GET http://localhost:5000/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographers net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:10722
sendReq              @ angular.js:10515
serverRequest        @ angular.js:10222
processQueue         @ angular.js:14745
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14761
Scope.$eval          @ angular.js:15989
Scope.$digest        @ angular.js:15800
Scope.$apply         @ angular.js:16097
(anonymous function) @ angular.js:12226
eventHandler @ angular.js:3298*`
```

I originally thought this might be a CORS issue, so I tried using `$http.jsonp()`. This produced the same error. I know that there is something which is hindering my ability to access the API, but I do not know what or how to fix it.

My AngularJS module is as follows:

```
angular.module('myApp.choreographer', ['ngRoute'])

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/choreographer', {
    templateUrl: 'choreographer/choreographer.html',
    controller: 'choreographerCtrl'
    });
}])
.factory('choreographerService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://localhost:5000/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographers');
})
.controller('choreographerCtrl', function($scope, choreographerService) {
    var choreographers = choreographerService.query(function() {
        console.log(choreographers);
        }); //query() returns all the entries
    });
```

The flask API is as follows:

```
\#!env/bin/python  
from flask import Flask, jsonify  
from flask import abort  
from flask import request  

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
  return "Hello World!"

choreographers = [
             {
                "id":1,
                "firstName": "Danny",
                "lastName": "Boy",
                "email": "email@email.edu",
                "bio": "Biography for Danny."
              },
              {
                "id":2,
                "firstName": "Jessica",
                "lastName": "Martin",
                "email": "helloworld@smu.edu",
                "bio": "Biography text for Jessica"
              },
              {
                "id":3,
                "firstName": "John",
                "lastName": "Doe",
                "email": "test@pleasework.com",
                "bio": "Biography text for John"
              }
]

@app.route('/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographers', methods=['GET'])
def get_choreographers():
    return jsonify({'choreographers': choreographers})

@app.route('/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographer/<int:choreographer_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_choreographer(choreographer_id):
    choreographer = [choreographer for choreographer in choreographers if choreographer['id'] == choreographer_id]
    if len(choreographer) == 0:
        abort(404)
    return jsonify({'choreographer':choreographer[0]})

@app.route('/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographer', methods=['POST'])
def add_choreographer():
    if not request.json or not 'firstName' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    choreographer = {
        'id': choreographers[-1]['id'] + 1,
        'firstName': request.json['firstName'],
        'lastName': request.json.get('lastName',""),
        'email': request.json['email'],
        'bio': request.json['bio'],
    }

    choreographers.append(choreographer)

    return jsonify({'choreographers': choreographer}),201

@app.route('/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographers/<int:choreographer_id>', methods=['PUT'])
def update_choreographer(choreographer_id):
    choreographer = [choreographer for choreographer in choreographers if choreographer['id'] == choreographer_id]
    if len(choreographer) == 0:
        abort(404)
    if not request.json:
        abort(400)
    if 'firstName' in request.json and type(request.json['firstName']) != unicode:
        abort(400)
    if 'lastName' in request.json and type(request.json['lastName']) is not unicode:
        abort(400)
    choreographer[0]['firstName'] = request.json.get('firstName', choreographer[0]['firstName'])
    choreographer[0]['lastName'] = request.json.get('lastName', choreographer[0]['lastName'])
    choreographer[0]['email'] = request.json.get('email', choreographer[0]['email'])
    choreographer[0]['bio'] = request.json.get('bio', choreographer[0]['bio'])
    return jsonify({"choreographer": choreographer[0]})

@app.route('/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographers/<int:choreographer_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_choreographer(choreographer_id):
    choreographer = [choreographer for choreographer in choreographers if choreographer['id'] == choreographer_id]
    if len(choreographer) == 0:
        abort(404)
    choreographers.remove(choreographer[0])
    return jsonify({'result':True})

if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.run(debug=True)
```

My Angular tests the first GET method in the Flask API

Comment: please post error logs,so that we can review it

Comment: Thanks, @AakashShinde. Just updated the question to include my new implementation. After researching the question a little further, I found ngResource, a module which is used to handle requests from a RESTful API.

Comment: Connection refused would usually indicate that there is nothing open on that port (5000).  Are you certain your LAMP server is running on port 5000 and the same server you are running the browser on?  Is it a Linux server?  If so, what is the result of running 'lsof :5000'?

Comment: add ngResource to app dependencies, $resource('http://localhost:5000/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographers/:id'), then $scope.choreographers = choreographerService.query(); make sure that you run everything on the localhost (browser and server) - otherwise change "localhost:5000" to your server address

Comment: Does it work if you put in browser
`http://localhost:5000/choreographer/api/v1.0/choreographers`
?